# How do you use table models

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I understand the core concept, but how do you use Qt table models? How would you go by creating a model class and finally does a QTableView auto-reload when data is changed.

Comment: Take a look at the demo in QTCreator ... **SQL>** _Table Model_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reading the [Qt Model/View Tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/modelview.html)?